# UIView layer renderInContext not drawing to image context

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I'm trying to draw a view's layer to a CGGraphicsImageContext using renderInContext, however the view layer is not displaying on the resultant UIImage.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledImage.size);
[scaledImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledImage.size.width, scaledImage.size.height)];


[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *croppedImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() croppedImage:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, scaledImage.size.height - (60 + 44))];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

My drawRect method for the view is as follows:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CALayer *background = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    background.opacity = 0.4;
    background.frame = self.bounds;

    [self.layer addSublayer:background];

    CATextLayer *textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    textLayer.string = _poseName;
    textLayer.fontSize = 19;
    textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    textLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    CGSize textSize = [_poseName sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19]
                        constrainedToSize:textLayer.bounds.size
                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    textLayer.position = CGPointMake(160, self.bounds.size.height - textSize.height/2);

    [self.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
}
```

The view's layers are displaying correctly when the app is running however, the view is not rendering to the graphics context as I would expect.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please post links to screenshots showing the image as it appears in your app and the image as it's rendered, so we can see the difference?  Also, I don't recognize that `-[UIImage croppedImage:]` method.  If that's more custom code you should post it too, in case the bug is in the `croppedImage:` method.